# Empty Data Connections

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

The `.mdf` file and `.ldf` files were created in my local folder. But when I clicked on Server Explorer, it shows no data connection.

I am not getting any error and able to create and view the data. Just that I am unable to view the data connection as stated in the tutorial here : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application#set-up-ef-to-use-a-sql-server-express-localdb-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMFTz.png)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for Visual Studio Community users:

1. Open up Server Explorer
2. Click on SQL Server Object Explorer
3. Right click SQL Server
4. Select Local
5. Choose your DB name